# SML [circularity] error

Tags: sml

I'd like to write one function that extracts only the odd numbers from a list. Something like:

```
fun odd(nil) = nil
  | odd(a::nil) = a
  | odd(a::(b::c)) = a::odd(c);
```

But it causes this error:

> operator and operand don't agree [circularity]

Answer (score 7):

In your second case `odd(a::nil) = a` you return `a`, which is a single element. In the other two cases you return a list. If you change it to `odd(a::nil) = [a]`, so all cases return a list, it works.

Comment: Yes You are rigth. Thank You. Marco